# Deserialize JSON string into List[Map[String, Any]] in Scala

Tags: json, scala

This is the code:

```
def fromStrings(json: String): List[Map[String, Any]] = {
    implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats

    parse(json).extract[List[Map[String, Any]]]
  }
```

This is the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon cannot be cast to scala.collection.mutable.Seq
```

I'm able to deserialize single objects and I thought it would be easy to extend to a list, but it's not working as expected. I've looked up this error but I haven't found a case where it's related to what I'm doing here.

This is the data I'm testing with:

```
[
  {
    "schemaVersion": "1",
    "data": {
      "new_data": {
        "case_id": "1"
      },
      "id": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "schemaVersion": "2",
    "data": {
      "new_data": {
        "case_id": "2"
      },
      "id": "2"
    }
  },
  {
    "schemaVersion": "3",
    "data": {
      "new_data": {
        "case_id": "3"
      },
      "id": "3"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: `Any` is generally a symptom of bad design, and prevent any typeclass based conversions.

Comment: Is there another option? I have no idea what's going to be in the json I'm deserializing

Comment: Have a proper design/model

Comment: Thanks, that's really insightful /s

Comment: Use [Dijon](https://github.com/pathikrit/dijon) FTW! It is much handy, safer, and more efficient than [json4s](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?q=is%3Aissue+denial).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def deserializeObjects(json: String): Seq[Map[String, Any]] = {
   implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats
   val jsons = JsonParser.parseString(json).getAsJsonArray.iterator()

   var maps: Seq[Map[String, Any]] = Seq()
   while (jsons.hasNext) {
     val s = jsons.next().getAsJsonObject.toString
     maps = maps :+ parse(s).extract[Map[String, Any]]
   }
   maps
}
```